# Клиент-серверное приложение (Windows - Android)

Tags: java, android, c, клиент-сервер

Вообщем надо сделать приложение, в котором сервер будет пк, а клиенты андроид.

1.**Будет ли проблемно** написать сервер на С, а клиент на Java.

```
 2. Правильно ли будет сделать так: Есть БД SQL, пакеты от клиентов
присылаются на сервер, а сервер в
свою очередь заносит данные в БД, и
обратная связь по такому же
принципу? или есть другие принципы?
```

И вообще в какую сторону копать?

Есть ли какая нибудь литература (на русском) именно по этому вопросу?

Answer (score 1):

**Ответы по порядку:**

1) Да, писать клиента на СИ будет достаточно проблематично. Язык низкоуровневый, а потому, многие операции низкого уровня возлагаются на ваши плечи, что может привести в конечном итоге к невозможности сконцентрироваться на основной задаче - логике самого клиента. Так что лучше бы вам выбрать что-то, что избавляет от ненужных проблем. Я бы посоветовал C#. Можете Java, если умеете эффективно использовать. Плюс, высокий уровень несет в себе и такую технологию, как виртуализация кода, что, грубо говоря, позволит создать кроссплатформенный клиент для настольных ОС.

2) На сервере же лучше создать какой-нибудь скрипт(на PHP, например), который, в свою очередь, будет иметь GET-интерфейс(API, если угодно). Скрипт будет получать данные( как от клиента, так и от мобильного устройства ) и производить манипуляции с ними( запись в БД, удаление, выдачу данных и т.д ). В качестве СУБД можете использовать, что угодно. MySQL  самый оптимальный и доступный вариант.

Comment: @0xFFh А если на сервере будет крутиться не скрипт, а Java-программа? Такое решение будет медленнее?

Answer (score 0):

Клиент + сервер, протоколы передачи данных, работа с СУБД.
Основные ключевые моменты для поиска информации.